# jQuery KeyPress send data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

Please take a look at the following code...

```
$("#page_info_select_box").live("keypress",function(){

var sele = "domain";
var inp =  $("#page_info_select_box").val(); 
if(inp != null)
{   var start = "";

    var i ;

    $.get("admin/get_users_page",{qry:inp,selector:sele},function(data){
//alert(data);

  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    start = start + "<option>" +data[i].tp1+"</option>";
  }
  $("#select_page_domain").html(start);
},"json");


}

});
```

The keypress event is working but its does not sending the correct text in the textbox.

whats wrong with me ?

if i type "ST" it only sending `S` not `T`
if i type `SFY` it seding `SF` not `Y` .

`page_info_select_box` is added dynamically.

Comment: Some events are not supported by some browsers. Be sure to check this link - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

http://jsfiddle.net/PfnT9/1/ (check it with firebug or chrome console)